# TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I dont get why this wont work, could do with some help here

```
function User(username, ID) {
    this.username = username;
    this.ID = ID;
}

var user = User("",1)
console.log(user)
```

Comment: Should work fine if you use like `new User("name",123);`

Comment: Can you please provide the full code ?

Comment: added the "full code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably creating the object in a wrong way, where `this` is not refering to the `new` instance:

```js
function User(username, ID) {
    this.username = username;
    this.ID = ID;
}
let user = new User("john",1);
console.log(user);
```

Comment: You will not get the error even if you remove new keyword becasue in that case this will refer to global window object.